# Setup of PyDev and Eclipse for Blender Add-Ons

Tags: python

I followed the instructions in this [ebook Programming Add-Ons for Blender 2.5](http://airplanes3d.net/pydev-000_e.xml) to setup a development environment.

Currently I try to debug an installed [add-on called Bloop](http://dm.tzi.de/bloop/) although it seems to work, eclipse still shows many error messages like:

```
class Mapping(object):

    def __init__(self, joint=None, id=None, bone=None, other=None):
        ...
        self.bone_matrix = bpy.bloop.armature.matrix_world.inverted() * self.bone.bone.matrix_local.inverted()
                               ^^^^
                               ErrorMsg: Undefined variable from import: bloop
```

The external libraries are configured as follows:

[image]

Blenders version is 2.67, the add-on was developed for 2.59. I have absolutely no experience with Python in blender.

Another type of errors is:

```
Unresolved import: MappingSet   bloop.py

from .mapping_set import MappingSet
```

Where MappingSet is in the same folder as bloop.py which tries to import.

The projects structure is as follows (I don't have a source folder since I want to edit in place)

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this question is off topic, and relates more to eclipse than it does to Blender.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112715/how-do-i-fix-pydev-undefined-variable-from-import-errors) answer your question?

Comment: I think it's still Blender related enough

Comment: @grc Thanks, this indeed help for one type of error messages, I added another type.

Comment: @stacker You could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631377/unresolved-import-issues-with-pydev-and-eclipse). If that doesn't work, you might have more luck just downloading Blender 2.59. Blender is portable so it's fine having multiple versions on your computer.

Comment: @grc Thanks again, unfortunatly the link describes how to add  external libraries which I already have, the problem here is that in the bloop source folder MappingSet from .mapping_set.py isn't resolved.

Comment: @stacker Since these errors are all coming from pydev, have you tried running it outside of eclipse?

Comment: @grc Yes seems that PyDev introduces more issues than it helps. I give up using PyDev until someone else has another idea.

Comment: A workaround to suppress at least the error messages is using `#@UnresolvedImport` and  `#@UndefinedVariable` at the end of those lines.

Comment: @stacker wasn't able to comment properly on this before but it relates more to Eclipse than Blender. Pertaining to your edit, I think this should be the other way around, IMO this belongs more on SO.

Comment: Posted on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821865/setup-of-pydev-and-eclipse-for-blender-add-ons

Comment: See the [discusion for this question on meta](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68/migrating-blender-related-questions-from-other-se-sites)